# Can't stratify output based on different headings and their corresponding paragraphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to fetch each heading and their corresponding paragraphs from the html elements below. The results should be stored within a dictionary. Whatever I've tried so far produces ludicrously haphazard output. I intentionally did not paste the current output only because of brevity of space.

```
html = """
<h1>a Complexity Profile</h1>
<p>Since time immemorial humans have...</p>
<p>How often have we been told</p>

<h2>INDIVIDUAL AND COLLECTIVE BEHAVIOR</h2>
<p>Building a model of society based...</p>
<p>All macroscopic systems...</p>

<h3>COMPLEXITY PROFILE</h3>
<p>It is much easier to think about the...</p>
<p>A formal definition of scale considers...</p>
<p>The complexity profile counts...</p>

<h2>CONTROL IN HUMAN ORGANIZATIONS</h2>
<p>Using this argument it is straightforward...</p>

<h2>Conclusion</h2>
<p>There are two natural conclusions...</p>
"""
```

I've tried with (producing messy output):

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
data = []
for item in soup.select("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6"):
    d = {}
    d['title'] = item.text
    d['text'] = [i.text for i in item.find_next_siblings('p')]
    data.append(d)

print(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
```

***Output I wish to get***:

```
[
    {
        "title": "a Complexity Profile",
        "text": [
            "Since time immemorial humans have...",
            "How often have we been told",
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "INDIVIDUAL AND COLLECTIVE BEHAVIOR",
        "text": [
            "Building a model of society based...",
            "All macroscopic systems...",
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "COMPLEXITY PROFILE",
        "text": [
            "It is much easier to think about the...",
            "A formal definition of scale considers...",
            "The complexity profile counts...",
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "CONTROL IN HUMAN ORGANIZATIONS",
        "text": [
            "Using this argument it is straightforward...",
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Conclusion",
        "text": [
            "There are two natural conclusions..."
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tricky problem.  I think you have to handle things linearly:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
data = []
pending = {}
for item in soup.select("h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p"):
    if item.name == 'p':
        pending['text'].append( item.text )
    else:
        if pending:
            data.append(pending)
        pending = {'title': item.text, 'text': [] }
data.append( pending )

print(json.dumps(data,indent=4))
```

Output:

```
timr@tims-gram:~/src$ python x.py
[
    {
        "title": "a Complexity Profile",
        "text": [
            "Since time immemorial humans have...",
            "How often have we been told"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "INDIVIDUAL AND COLLECTIVE BEHAVIOR",
        "text": [
            "Building a model of society based...",
            "All macroscopic systems..."
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "COMPLEXITY PROFILE",
        "text": [
            "It is much easier to think about the...",
            "A formal definition of scale considers...",
            "The complexity profile counts..."
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "CONTROL IN HUMAN ORGANIZATIONS",
        "text": [
            "Using this argument it is straightforward..."
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Conclusion",
        "text": [
            "There are two natural conclusions..."
        ]
    }
]
timr@tims-gram:~/src$
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `find_previous()` to check if you're in right "section":

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
r = re.compile(r"h\d+", flags=re.I)

data = []
for h in soup.find_all(name=r):
    data.append({"title": h.get_text(strip=True), "text": []})
    p = h.find_next_sibling("p")
    while p and p.find_previous(name=r) == h:
        data[-1]["text"].append(p.get_text())
        p = p.find_next_sibling("p")

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```json
[
    {
        "title": "a Complexity Profile",
        "text": [
            "Since time immemorial humans have...",
            "How often have we been told"
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "INDIVIDUAL AND COLLECTIVE BEHAVIOR",
        "text": [
            "Building a model of society based...",
            "All macroscopic systems..."
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "COMPLEXITY PROFILE",
        "text": [
            "It is much easier to think about the...",
            "A formal definition of scale considers...",
            "The complexity profile counts..."
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "CONTROL IN HUMAN ORGANIZATIONS",
        "text": [
            "Using this argument it is straightforward..."
        ]
    },
    {
        "title": "Conclusion",
        "text": [
            "There are two natural conclusions..."
        ]
    }
]
```

---

EDIT: Good idea is using `itertools.takewhile`:

```
import re
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import takewhile

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
r = re.compile(r"h\d+", flags=re.I)

data = []
for h in soup.find_all(name=r):
    data.append({"title": h.get_text(strip=True), "text": []})
    for p in takewhile(lambda p: p.find_previous(name=r) == h, h.find_next_siblings("p")):
        data[-1]["text"].append(p.get_text())

print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

---

Using just list comprehension:

```py
data = [
    {
        "title": h.get_text(strip=True),
        "text": [
            p.get_text()
            for p in takewhile(
                lambda p: p.find_previous(name=r) == h,
                h.find_next_siblings("p"),
            )
        ],
    }
    for h in soup.find_all(name=r)
]
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both of the answers. Given that your answer solves the issue perfectly. I just prioritized the answer I got first. However, I thought you would suggest something like `takewhile`. Thanks.

Comment: @SMTH Good idea with the `itertools.takewhile`. I added it to my answer.